# XSL validation while transformation

Tags: java, validation, xslt

I'm using the following piece of code to do XSL transformation :

```
Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(request.toString()));
Source xsl = new StreamSource(XSLPath);
                
StringWriter destination = new StringWriter();
Result result = new StreamResult(destination);
        
TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer;
transformer = transFactory.newTransformer(xsl);
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

The `XSLPath` variable passes the file location to the `.xsl` file.

I need to know whether the `transFactory.newTransformer(xsl)` does any kind of internal validation first of the xsl file itself. If not, then is there a way we can do validation of the xsl file, before performing the transformation?

I have a code to validate an xsd file, but, I believe the same code wouldn't work for an xsl. I still tried that as well, but it always throw some or the other `SAXException` about Non-white spaces not being allowed on most of the lines.

Comment: Could you explain from where the 'request' object is coming from? I am new to java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the first thing the XSLT processor does is to validate and compile the stylesheet. (Why did you have to ask? Just introduce an error, and see what happens!)

You might find it useful to set an ErrorListener to make sure that your application can capture the error messages.

If you are using the same stylesheet repeatedly for many transformations, it is much more efficient to use newTemplates() to create a Templates object so you only do the validation/compilation once. Think of the Templates object as the compiled stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Michcael. That's exactly what I thought! Just wanted to confirm whether this approach is fine, or, there is some other industry standard to be followed.